# Android Jetpack Compose material3 rememberPullRefreshState unresolved reference

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

Android Jetpack Compose material3 rememberPullRefreshState unresolved reference

```kotlin
  val isRefreshing by viewModel.isRefreshing.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

  val pullRefreshState = rememberPullRefreshState(refreshing, { viewModel.refresh() })
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. The compose material3 version >= 1.2.0 has updated the API for the pull-to-refresh component.

See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3?hl=zh-cn#1.2.0

Usage: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/pulltorefresh/PullToRefreshState

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.material3.LinearProgressIndicator
import androidx.compose.material3.ListItem
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.pulltorefresh.rememberPullToRefreshState
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.nestedScroll

var itemCount by remember { mutableStateOf(15) }
val state = rememberPullToRefreshState()
if (state.isRefreshing) {
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        // fetch something
        delay(1500)
        itemCount += 5
        state.endRefresh()
    }
}
Box(Modifier.nestedScroll(state.nestedScrollConnection)) {
    LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        if (!state.isRefreshing) {
            items(itemCount) {
                ListItem({ Text(text = "Item ${itemCount - it}") })
            }
        }
    }
    PullToRefreshContainer(state = pullRefreshState, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter))

//    or

//    if (state.isRefreshing) {
//        LinearProgressIndicator()
//    } else {
//        LinearProgressIndicator(progress = { state.progress })
//    }
}
```